# QLPreviewController query (Quicklook framework)

Tags: xcode, quicklook

I'm trying to use the QLPreviewController in order to preview some files.

I have the following problem:

If I access the file directly :

```
#define kStringURLViewControllerPDF @"http://myweb.com/PreviewController_Class.pdf"

fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kStringURLViewControllerPDF];
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

//settnig the datasource property to self
previewController.dataSource = self;

//pusing the QLPreviewController to the navigation stack
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

---

then the file is displayed RIGHT, so if I access the file by a php query :

```
#define kStringURLViewControllerPDF @"http://myweb.com/ios/download.php?up=698"
```

then the file is displayed BAD, with bad codification characters.

So through my browser the "http://myweb.com/ios/download.php?up=698" address download then file RIGHT.

Anyone can help me ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Advanced thanks

Comment: maybe QLPreviewController does not accept generic urls... It is possible that it checks for the file ending before downloading anything